# Why CREATE/ALTER schema with current date cannot accept any space or symbol using POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, date, schema, alter

Why `CREATE` or `ALTER` schema cannot accept any space or symbol using `POSTGRESQL`? I kept getting error msg for creating schema with current date.

This will give you schemaname with current date

```
select 'test_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM_DD_YYYY') AS SCHEMA_NAME;
```

but if you want to use it for `ALTER RENAME TO`, it wont accept. I've tried several ways. It seem it wont work. Anyone face this before?

I try to use this script:

```
ALTER SCHEMA test RENAME TO 'test_'|| to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM_DD_YYYY') AS SCHEMA_NAME';
```